# Stabilizer of the Bryant-Harvey associative calibration

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, multilinear-algebra

View $\mathbb{R}^{4n+4} = \mathbb{H}^{n+1}$ with its standard inner product.  Right multiplication $R_I, R_J, R_K$ by the unit quaternions $I,J,K$ defines orthogonal complex structures on $\mathbb{R}^{4n+4}$ with corresponding $2$-forms denoted $\omega_I, \omega_J, \omega_K$.  In this notation, the **generalized Cayley 4-form** with respect to $K$ is
$$\Phi_K = -\frac{1}{2}\omega_I^2 - \frac{1}{2}\omega_J^2 + \frac{1}{2}\omega_K^2 \in \Lambda^4(\mathbb{R}^{4n+4})^*.$$
This $4$-form was first considered by [Bryant and Harvey](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1989-02-01/S0894-0347-1989-0953169-8/S0894-0347-1989-0953169-8.pdf) and shown to be a calibration.  Under the standard $\text{SO}(4n+4)$-action, they showed that the stabilizer of $\Phi_K$ is equal to $\text{Spin}(7)$ when $n = 1$, and equal to $\text{Sp}(n+1)(\mathbb{S}^1 \cup R_I\mathbb{S}^1)$ when $n \geq 2$.

On $\mathbb{R}^{4n+3} = \text{Im}(\mathbb{H}) \oplus \mathbb{H}^n$, the **generalized associative 3-form** with respect to $K$ is
$$\phi_K := e_1 \,\lrcorner\,\Phi_K$$
where $e_1 = (1, 0, \ldots, 0) \in \mathbb{H} \oplus \mathbb{H}^n$.  Again, Bryant and Harvey show that $\phi_K$ is a calibration.  They also compute that
$$\phi_K = e_I \wedge e_J \wedge e_K - e_I \wedge \omega_I - e_J \wedge \omega_J + e_K \wedge \omega_K,$$
where $(e_I, e_J, e_K)$ is the basis of $1$-forms on $\text{Im}(\mathbb{H})$ dual to the standard basis $(I, J, K)$.  My questions are:

> 1. Under the $\text{SO}(4n+3)$-action, what is the stabilizer $G$ of the $3$-form $\phi_K$?  When $n = 1$, I can see that $G = \text{G}_2$, but I'm not sure about $n \geq 2$.  Naively, I might guess $G = \text{Sp}(n)(\mathbb{S}^1 \cup R_I\mathbb{S}^1)$.
> 2. Does $G$ act transitively on the Grassmannian of $\phi_K$-calibrated $3$-planes?  I know this is true for $n = 1$, so my question concerns $n \geq 2$.